# Split string into list of substrings of different character types

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a spell checker that takes a text file as input and outputs the file with spelling corrected.

The program should preserve formatting and punctuation.

I want to split the input text into a list of string tokens such that each token is either 1 or more: `word, punctuation, whitespace, or digit characters`.

For example:

Input:

> words.txt:
>
> asdf don't ]'.'..;'' as12....asdf.
>   asdf

Input as list:

> ["asdf" , " " , "don't" , " " , "]'.'..;''" , " " , "as" , "12" ,
>   "...." , "asdf" , "." , "\n" , "asdf"]

Words like `won't` and `i'll` should be treated as a single token.

Having the data in this format would allow me to process the tokens like so:

```
String output = "";

for(String token : tokens) {
    if(isWord(token)) {
        if(!inDictionary(token)) {
            token = correctSpelling(token);
        }
    }
    output += token;
}
```

So my main question is how can i split a string of text into a list of substrings as described above? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: It is not clear what your input looks like or how you want to split.  For example, to distinguish a certain character as being a token versus a part of a string will be difficult and will require a custom tokenizer.

Comment: this is a hard problem and one universal regex won't be sufficient, as there are many uncertainties. you may consider to define a **BNF** for it to retrieve the tokens.

Comment: @dotvav i've tried using split(regex) and scanner.next(regex) but as nafas said, it's hard to define the right regex.

Comment: @nafas yes, this problem is probably too hard for me it seems. I'm not sure what a BNF is, also.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this kind of problem is to hand it off to dedicated lexers. Failing that you can write your own finite state machine to do it character by character. I'd probably steer clear of `split()` or any other regex-based solution.

Comment: @Nataly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form . if you don't know what it is, then ignore it... I know its hard because I do loads of String processing and splitting for different input is never 100%

Comment: I think regex is not the best fit for this problem. I'd build a small [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), reading characters one by one and classifying them for tokenization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difficulty here would be to find the regex that matches what you consider to be a "word". For my example I consider ' to be part of a word if it's proceeded by a letter or if the following character is a letter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "asdf don't ]'.'..;'' as12....asdf.\nasdf";

        //The pattern: 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Alpha}][\\p{Alpha}']*|'[\\p{Alpha}]+");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
        //If you want to collect the words
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Now find something from the start
        int pos = 0; 
        while(m.find(pos)) {
            //Add everything from starting position to beginning of word
            result.append(in.substring(pos, m.start()));

            //Handle dictionary logig
            String token = m.group();
            words.add(token); //not used actually
            if(!inDictionary(token)) {
                token = correctSpelling(token);
            }
            //Add to result
            result.append(token);
            //Repeat from end position
            pos = m.end();
        }
        //Append remainder of input
        result.append(in.substring(pos));

        System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because I like solving puzzles, I tried the following and I think it works fine:

```
public class MyTokenizer {
    private final String str;
    private int pos = 0;

    public MyTokenizer(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return pos < str.length();
    }

    public String next() {
        int type = getType(str.charAt(pos));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(hasNext() && (str.charAt(pos) == '\'' || type == getType(str.charAt(pos)))) {
            sb.append(str.charAt(pos));
            pos++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private int getType(char c) {
        String sc = Character.toString(c);
        if (sc.matches("\\d")) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (sc.matches("\\w")) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (sc.matches("\\s")) {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (sc.matches("\\p{Punct}")) {
            return 3;
        }
        else {
            return 4;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyTokenizer mt = new MyTokenizer("asdf don't ]'.'..;'' as12....asdf.\nasdf");
        while(mt.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(mt.next());
        }
    }
}
```